# Enquadramento de imagem

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou tentando colocar uma imagem de 704x480 em uma ImageView, mas ela fica flutuando com espaços em cima e em baixo.

Ex.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/demo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que quer que aconteça? Quer que ocupe a tela toda?

Comment: Tente usar a propriedade android:adjustViewBounds="true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode brincar um pouco com o `android:scaleType` do `Imageview`.

Por padrão ele vem como `fitCenter`, por isso você vê a imagem no centro, e a parte de cima e de baixo preto. Tente por exemplo setar o valor da propriedade com `fitXY`, você verá que a imagem vai se ajustar ao tamanho do seu `Imageview`, independente do tamanho da tela do seu dispositivo.

[Neste link](http://etcodehome.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) tem uma lista completa  com cada tipo de escala e um exemplo de cada uma.

---

Você pode também usar a dica sugerida pelo **@Bruno Romualdo** nos comentários e utilizar o `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`, neste caso será o `Imageview` que vai se ajustar a sua imagem.